# Concurrent multipart/form-data requests rejected by .NET api

Tags: .net, multipartform-data

I'm implementing a multi file uploader using Angular + .NET.
The user selects multiple files and the web app sends multiple post requests to my API.

Along with the binary, I'm sending some other properties in the form data request.
But only the binary/file changes across the different requests.

For some reason, only the last request is accepted and results in a successful upload.

[image]

My endpoint is only hit once, by the last request:

```
[HttpPost("asset")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(BinaryResponse), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(GenericResponse), StatusCodes.Status413RequestEntityTooLarge)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(GenericResponse), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(GenericResponse), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadBinary([FromForm] IFormFile file, [FromForm] BinaryRequest binary)
{
   //...
}
```

And the Angular service is called 3 times as expected:

```
uploadFile(version: string, product: string, asset: Asset) : Observable<HttpEvent<BinaryResult>> {
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('version', version);
  formData.append('file', asset.file);
  formData.append('operationalSystem', asset.operationalSystem);
  formData.append('architecture', asset.architecture);
  
  return super.postReporter<BinaryResult>('asset', formData);
}

//Base class:
protected postReporter<X>(sub: string, content: any) {
  return this.httpClient.post<X>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.base}/${sub}`, content, {
    reportProgress: true,
    observe: 'events',
  });
}
```

Are there any configurations that I could be missing to enable multiple requests to be accepted at once?

The only altered setting related to file upload is this:

```
builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this config in Startup.cs, .NET core 3.1:

```
        services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
        {
            x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // In case of multipart
        });
```